# Acceptability of questions that can be answered in two lines?

Tags: discussion, guidelines

Nearly all the questions that I ask on here can be answered by one or two lines, and have sometimes been answered in the comments and are usually due to me using the wrong keywords when trying to find the answer for myself. Here's a prime example of which I spent a few hours "Googling" a concept to no avail (a lot of the results were journal papers above my reading level):

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/134934/52419

Now are these types of questions acceptable here or should I be edging on trying a bit harder to solve it for myself before using this resource?

Also what is the proper etiquette to deal with questions that have been answered in the comments, do I delete the question so it doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 8):

> Also what is the proper etiquette to deal with questions that have been answered in the comments, do I delete the question so it doesn't remain unanswered?

No. You can either ask the person who left the comment to convert it into an answer (so that they can get the rep when it is up-voted/accepted), or you can answer the question yourself from the information in the comment.

Comment: Yeah the second part of that question was poorly thought out.

Comment: As a third person should I ask the one who provided the answer in comment to post an answer so the question won't appear as unanswered?

Comment: @BenceKaulics: Yes, and then if you get no response, go ahead and post the answer yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Think about it from this perspective: you had a clear idea of the problem you were facing, but were quite confident that there would be a solution to it. You googled for this solution using your knowledge about the topic and couldn't find it.

I expect there are others out there with the same issue, and the same prior knowledge: these people are likely to have the same struggle googling, but perhaps may end up in your question and find the right direction. In that the question can represent useful reference, if nothing else just for providing the right naming of the issue.

I think these questions have some value and should stay, but perhaps if the answer is a one-liner it could be expanded to provide more help and increase the chance of it being found.

Answer (score 2):

It's not that bad of a question.  That said, it's not asked in a way that makes it a question I'd want to try to answer, because its a little broad.  What you'd need here for my upvote is the missing paragraph, which is "here's what I've tried, or here's what I plan to try, and here's why I think I may have problems."

For what it's worth, I don't believe that question is answerable in two lines.  What you've been given in comments are simply search terms, some of which are pretty applicable to your situation, and some are way to general to be of real use, but none are answers to your question.  A *good* answer would be very long -- which is why I wouldn't consider taking this one on.